# Excel Regression - Training and Test Data

Tags: regression, excel

I am curious about the Excel regression function and evaluation of **training** and **test** data. Unlike using a program like R or Python where you state the values for your test and training data, Excel does not have this option with its regression set up. Does this mean that it assumes 100% of the values selected for the independent and dependent variables are **training** data?

Comment: Yes. You can specify the array of rows used for training, and then test the result on the rest of rows you had left for testing manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll elaborate on the first comment briefly.

When you run the regression model in Excel, be sure to select only that part of the data that you want to use as the training data set.  You can then generate the regression coefficients for the model.  Next, you will need to calculate the estimated values for the rest of the data (the test data set) manually.  From experience, one useful trick for this is to use the =SUMPRODUCT() formula, copy the coefficients to the top (or bottom) of each respective column, and then select the values in the row (using relative reference) and the values in this top row (using absolute reference).  *E.g.*, say your independent variables are in columns A:D; you run the model and copy the coefficients to the first row of these columns, A1, B1, C1, D1; then for each row, you calculate =SUMPRODUCT(A10:D10,A$1:D$1)+ _int_, where _int_ is the intercept calculate in the regression output.

Hope this helps...happy to clarify as need be.

**Addendum #1**
As requested in the comments, here is an example using excel.  First, here is some code that can be saved as a *.csv file

```
,,x,y,z,w,
TRAIN,,1.062,0.32,-0.836,-0.088,
TRAIN,,-0.455,0.438,0.391,1.53,
TRAIN,,0.368,1.552,-1.069,0.414,
TRAIN,,-0.295,0.069,-0.658,1.007,
TRAIN,,-0.176,0.523,-1.215,-0.385,
TRAIN,,1.167,-1.756,0.883,0.349,
TRAIN,,-0.108,-0.796,0.117,-1.438,
TRAIN,,-0.083,2.001,-0.518,0.989,
TRAIN,,1.366,-1.55,-1.541,-0.532,
TRAIN,,2.077,0.558,-0.22,0.308,
,,,,,,
,(intercept),x,y,z,w,w-hat
,0.37884,-0.02445,0.398,0.44039,,
TEST,,0.584,-0.018,1.267,0.159,
TEST,,-0.558,-0.98,-0.841,-2.006,
TEST,,0.586,-0.733,-1.074,-0.774,
TEST,,0.957,1.811,0.616,1.638,
TEST,,-0.055,0.509,1.362,-0.935,
TEST,,1.032,1.131,-0.617,-0.312,
TEST,,0.38,1.056,-1.341,-0.307,
TEST,,1.296,0.755,0.438,0.412,
TEST,,-1.117,0.289,-1.203,0.009,
TEST,,0.333,-0.839,0.32,0.209,
TEST,,-0.537,-1.077,1.116,-1.31,
TEST,,1.095,-0.516,-0.87,0.051,
TEST,,0.153,-0.119,-0.745,-0.408,
TEST,,0.043,-0.395,-0.521,-1.787,
TEST,,-0.984,-0.477,-0.482,-0.476,
```

If you save this as a *.csv and open in Excel, you can copy the following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C15:E15,C$14:E$14)+$B$14
```

into cell G15.  Then copy G15 down thru G29.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for clearing up that the Regression function does not automatically run the training/test split. In the example provided should I assume that you ran regression on the 11th row down for the independent columns as you wouldn't want to include the 9 data points being used in the test data sample from the 2nd row (directly after the coefficients) to the 10th row? I don't hate to add more effort as you have been helpful, but would you mind a small csv with the format you are describing if my understanding is off?

Comment: I've prepared an Excel demo...but I can't find a way to share the file on this system...hoping one of the moderators will advise.

Comment: I've figured a "reasonable" work around...see the Addendum #1 in the answer above.